# SQL: Get running row delta for records

Tags: sql

Let's say we have this table with columns `RowID` and `Call`:

```
RowID  Call   DesiredOut
1       A        0
2       A        0
3       B        
4       A        1
5       A        0
6       A        0
7       B
8       B
9       A        2
10      A        0
```

I want to SQL query the last column `DesiredOut` as follows:
Each time `Call` is 'A' go back until 'A' is found again and count the number of records which are in between two 'A' entries.

Example: `RowID` 4 has 'A' and the nearest predecessor is in `RowID` 2. Between `RowID` 2 and `RowID` 4 we have one `Call` 'B', so we count 1.

Is there an elegant and performant way to do this with ANSI SQL?

Comment: Is rowid auto generated and stored inside database?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query to find the previous `Call = A` row.  Then, you could count the number of rows between that row and the current row:

```
select  RowID
,       `Call`
,       (
        select  count(*)
        from    YourTable t2
        where   RowID < t1.RowID
                and RowID > coalesce(
                    (
                    select  RowID
                    from    YourTable t3
                    where   `Call` = 'A'
                            and RowID < t1.RowID
                    order by
                            RowID DESC
                    limit 1
                    ),0)
        )
from    YourTable t1
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af0f5/6/0)

Comment: @Juergen: strictly speaking that answer is not "ANSI SQL" btw.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this by first finding the `rowid` of the previous "A" value.  Then count the number of values in-between.

The following query implements this logic using correlated subqueries:

```
select t.*,
       (case when t.call = 'A'
             then (select count(*)
                   from table t3
                   where t3.id < t.id and t3.id > prevA
                  )
        end) as InBetweenCount
from (select t.*,
             (select max(rowid)
              from table t2
              where t2.call = 'A' and t2.rowid < t.rowid
             ) as prevA
      from table t
     ) t;
```

If you know that `rowid` is sequential with no gaps, you can just use subtraction instead of a subquery for the calculation in the outer query.

Comment: RowID has no gaps. I will try all answers and compare the runtimes, since the table in question is huge.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using window functions:

```
with flagged as (
  select *,
         case
            when call = 'A' and lead(call) over (order by rowid) <> 'A' then 'end'
            when call = 'A' and lag(call) over (order by rowid) <> 'A' then 'start'
          end as change_flag
  from calls
)
select t1.rowid,
       t1.call,
       case 
         when change_flag = 'start' then rowid - (select max(t2.rowid) from flagged t2 where t2.change_flag = 'end' and t2.rowid < t1.rowid) - 1
         when call = 'A' then 0
       end as desiredout
from flagged t1
order by rowid;
```

The CTE first marks the start and end of each "A"-Block and the final select then uses these markers to get the difference between the start of one block and the end of the previous one.

If the rowid is *not* gapless, you can easily add a gapless rownumber inside the CTE to calculate the difference.

I'm not sure about the performance though. I wouldn't be surprised if Gordon's answer is faster.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e1840/1

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, this will be pretty fast if the two columns are indexed.

```
select  r1.RowID, r1.CallID, isnull( R1.RowID - R2.RowID - 1, 0 ) as DesiredOut
from    RollCall R1
left join RollCall R2
    on  R2.RowID =(
        select  max( RowID )
        from    RollCall
        where   RowID < R1.RowID
            and CallID = 'A')
    and R1.CallID = 'A';
```

Here is the <kbd>[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27f17/4/0)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
SELECT a.rowid - b.rowid 
FROM table as a, 
     (SELECT rowid FROM table where rowid < a.rowid order by rowid) as b
WHERE <something>
ORDER BY a.rowid
```

As I cannot say which DBMS you are using this is more kind of pseudo code which could work based on your system.